# Ignore input styling only?

Tags: css, sass

How can I ignore input styling? I need to style only text inside a label and not inputs.

Here is my sass code:

This works for text only:

```
  text-transform: lowercase;
  &:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

This does not work:

```
  text-transform: lowercase;
  &:not(input[type=text]):first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

html:

```
      <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" value="option1" checked>make first letter uppercase here
        <input class="span5" type="text"> to
        <input class="span5" type="text">
      </label>
```

Comment: Is your label text behind the input? If not, this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Can you show the complete selector (generated CSS would also be helpful)?

Comment: That HTML is invalid:  labels are only allowed to be associated with one input element.  Perhaps a fieldset would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe avoid the problem altogether with a slight layout adjustment:

http://jsfiddle.net/TjRbd/

```
input[type="radio"] {
    float: left;
}
label {
    display: block;
}
.radio:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

<label class="radio">make first letter uppercase here
    <input type="radio" value="option1" checked />
</label>
```